# Gradient of Sin(x)^4 is not same when calculated from its derivative

Tags: python, numpy

When I calculate and plot the derivative of Sin(x)^4 by directly putting the derivative of it which is 4 Sin(x)^3 Cos(x) for x= [0 to 180 deg] using the following code I get the right result.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.power( np.sin(   np.deg2rad(range(0,180))    ),4 )   
c = 4 * np.sin( np.deg2rad(range(0,180) ))**3 * np.cos(np.deg2rad(range(0,180)))
plt.plot(a)
plt.plot(c)    
plt.show()
```

But when I try to do the same thing with the numpy Gradient function then it gives me a different result i.e. the gradient is simply like straight line. For example, using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = np.power( np.sin(   np.deg2rad(range(0,180))    ),4 )   
plt.plot(a)
plt.plot(np.gradient(a))    
plt.show()
```

I am still unable the understand the reason of the difference. Could any one please give me a clue why they are different ? 
Actually in simulation work I have set of values in an array and I need to calculate the derivative of them over phi=range(0,180).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not correctly specifying the spacing between samples (which defaults to 1), so the answer you have is incorrectly scaled.

Try:

```
a = np.power(np.sin(np.deg2rad(range(0,180))),4 )   
plt.plot(a)
plt.plot(np.gradient(a, np.deg2rad(1)))
```

Now `c` and `np.gradient(a, np.deg2rad(1))` should be almost identical.